# Writing frequently to a log.txt in a Rust program

Tags: linux, rust, server, buffer

I am writing a web server in Rust and want to implement some form of logging.

The easiest way to do so is to just write to a log.txt every time a client sends a request.

The code would look like this:

```
let log = format!("Request received!\n");
let file = OpenOptions::new()
    .append(true)
    .open("log.txt")
    .unwrap();
let mut buffer = BufWriter::new(file);
buffer.write(log.as_ref()).unwrap();
```

Yet, unless the OS writes everything to an intermediate cache before flushing to the file, this way may result in multiple writes to the hardware in a very short time, which doesn't feel as a good thing, and could even damage the hardware.

In modern systems the contents are written in a buffer (either of the OS or of the hardware itself) before flushed to the storage device, but this is not always guaranteed.

Can the code above be rewritten or adjusted (perhaps with some custom flag?) so that the log is always written in an intermediate buffer of the OS?

Yes, I can write everything to an character buffer in the program, and flush the contents to the file periodically. But this can result to data loss if the server is abnormally terminated and I want to avoid it.

Thank you in advance

Comment: _Please_ use a proper logging framework. I suggest [`tracing`](https://docs.rs/tracing).

Comment: In what way do you envision that this "could even damage the hardware"?

Comment: I second the usage of tracing, and in the future if you want buffered write calls from std check out [`std::io::BufWriter`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/struct.BufWriter.html). Edit: I see you're using BufWriter, what's the issue?

Comment: @ScottHunter: If e.g. using an HDD, frequent writes on the disk are a problem.

Comment: @MeetTitan: Does the BufWriter *guarantee* that the log is not written directly to the disk? If  the function is called 1000 times in a second (as can happen in a server), and the function opens the file and appends to it, won't that mean that the program attempts to write 1000 times on the same file on the disk? The OS should prevent this situation, but will it?

Comment: If you share the file instance then it won't. If you don't then it will.

Comment: @GeoMldr, if you write to the *same file descriptor* with *the same BufWriter* you're by default guaranteed 8KiB of buffer between you and the file system, assuming nothing flushes or drops early.

Comment: _"I can write everything to an character buffer in the program [...] But this can result in data loss"_ There is an ever-present risk of data loss as long as the data is not on disk, whether it's in a userspace cache, the kernel page cache, or some hardware buffer on its way to the disk. `fsync` can also return before the data reaches the disk.